# Migração do Blogger para domínio não carrega

Tags: blogger, domínio

Tenho um blog no [blogger.com](http://blogger.com), comprei um domínio e já está configurado(apontado), mas olhem o que está acontecendo.

Site **SEM** domínio:

[image: O site sem o domínio]

Site **COM** domínio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me explicar o que está acontecendo e se isso é normal?

Comment: Como estão as configurações do `CNAME`, `A`, etc no seu servidor DNS?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nos passos para configurar o domínio no [artigo de suporte da google](https://support.google.com/blogger/troubleshooter/1233381?hl=en#ts=1734115)

Answer (score 1):

Abrindo [sua página](http://www.seriextreme.net/) No console do Chrome recebi os seguintes erros:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://sites.google.com/site/3f2x4a/1/jquery.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
Refused to execute script from 'https://sites.google.com/site/3f2x4a/1/bootstrap.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
Refused to execute script from 'https://sites.google.com/site/3f2x4a/1/bootstrap-select.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Refused to execute script from 'https://sites.google.com/site/3f2x4a/test/boostrap-blog.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
Uncaught ReferenceError: AddFilm is not defined
Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.
```

O que acontece é que você fez upload dos arquivos `.js` do Bootstrap e jQuery para [esse endereço do Google Sites](https://sites.google.com/site/3f2x4a/1) que está servindo os recursos com `Content-Type: text/html` e `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`. Essa combinação de cabeçalhos está efetivamente dizendo para seu navegador não abrir esses arquivos como se fossem JavaScript.

Para arrumar o problema você pode usar versões do jQuery e Bootstrap hospedadas em uma CDN ou em um servidor qualquer próprio para esse tipo de coisa. Exemplos:

- [jQuery na CDN da Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery)
- [Bootstrap na MaxCDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)

Eu também recomendaria mover quaisquer outros recursos hoje hospedados em `sites.google.com` (style sheets, imagens, etc) para serviços próprios para hospedagem, evitando assim problemas posteriores.